# Blank PDF downloaded from Google Apps Script and Drive API

Tags: google-apps-script

I'm trying to download a PDF file from Drive, in a web app using GAS. A PDF file is download, but the pages are blank. I can open the file in a browser or in Adobe Acrobat.

In GAS, I get the file using Drive API.

```
function downloadPDF(){
  let url = "https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v3/files/<file id>?supportsAllDrives=true&alt=media";

  let response = getGoogleAPI(url); // A function I created call the Drive API
  Logger.log("Response: %s", response); // This shows binary data

  return Utilities.base64Encode(response.getContent());
  
}
```

In the front end I have the following code:

```
function getPDF(){

    google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(function(response){
      $("#overlay").hide(); 
      
      let decoded = atob(response);
      console.log(decoded); // This shows the same binary data as from Apps Script
      
      let blob = new Blob(decoded, {type: "application/pdf"});

      const objectUrl = URL.createObjectURL(blob);

      const link = document.createElement('a')

      link.setAttribute('href', objectUrl)
      link.setAttribute('download', "test.pdf")
      link.style.display = 'none'

      document.body.appendChild(link)
    
      link.click()
    
      document.body.removeChild(link)
      
    }).downloadPDF();
}
```

Does anyone know what the problem is?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

I saw this post at read the reply from @Tanaike.

I changed this line of code:

```
link.setAttribute('href', objectUrl)
```

To this:

```
link.setAttribute('href', 'data:text/html;base64,' + response)
```

And it worked!